# SQL Server & PHP sqlsrv_fetch_array returns null when result set has only one row

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I am trying to get data from sql server in PHP.
My code is like:

```
$conn = "...";
$sql = "SELECT A.* FROM A 
        LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
        WHERE A.First_Name = 'Mary'";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if( sqlsrv_fetch($stmt) === false) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   echo $row['Last_Name'];
}
```

When there is only one row in the result set, it returns null. But I could get result using sqlsrv_get_field. What is the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
if( sqlsrv_fetch($stmt) === false) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

fetches the one row. After that, there are no more rows to fetch in the while loop.

Instead, remove the fetch call and just evaluate `$stmt`. It will be false if the query failed.

```
if($stmt === false) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```